# Cypher query to find circular reference

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the example found here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=qzjrxu, how would I identify nodes with relationships that end back to the starting node?

IE: joe -> bill -> tom -> joe AND matt -> matt

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small to medium graphs, this should return nodes suffering from a circular reference and the path itself:

```
MATCH (e)
WHERE SIZE((e)<-[:ManagedBy]-()) <> 0 
AND SIZE(()<-[:ManagedBy]-(e)) <> 0
MATCH path = (e)<-[:ManagedBy*]-(e) 
RETURN e, path
```

EDIT

I made a small change to first filter out nodes which do not have incoming and outgoing :ManagedBy relationships, those will never have a cycle.

Also it's highly recommended to use labels to reduce the nodes processed to the smallest set.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your problem and size of your graph you could try `apoc.nodes.cycles` from the apoc extension.

[Documentation of that function](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.nodes/apoc.nodes.cycles/)

With that you could run something like:

```
MATCH (e)
WITH collect(e) AS e_list
CALL apoc.nodes.cycles(e_list, {relTypes: ['XYZ'], maxDepth: 100}) 
YIELD path RETURN path
```

It is better to reduce the number of nodes beforehand by filtering etc., especially with a large database.